# AAD not providing refresh_token when requesting offline_access

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

For using Microsoft Graph in our application, I need a token for a specific user. I retrieve a bearer token form Azure Active Directory, but it is missing a `refresh_token`. It appears that the `offline_access` permission is being removed from the scopes.

The body of the request I'm sending to the `/token` endpoint is:

```
{
    code=*somecode*, 
    client_id=*my clientid*, 
    client_secret=*my clientsecret*, 
    redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080/msgraph/callback, 
    scope=profile Calendars.Read User.ReadBasic.All email User.Read offline_access Calendars.Read.Shared openid, 
    grant_type=authorization_code
}
```

I do not use implicit grants. The endpoint I connect to is V2.

In the App registration, I have added all the permissions from the sent scope.

In the token response, all of the requested scopes are returned, *except* for `offline_access`. The `refresh_token` is left empty but I do not receive any errors.

The manifest from the MSGraph administration is

```
{
    "id": "xxxx",
    "acceptMappedClaims": null,
    "accessTokenAcceptedVersion": 2,
    "addIns": [],
    "allowPublicClient": null,
    "appId": "xxxxx",
    "appRoles": [],
    "oauth2AllowUrlPathMatching": false,
    "createdDateTime": "2018-06-07T07:53:26Z",
    "groupMembershipClaims": null,
    "identifierUris": [],
    "informationalUrls": {
        "termsOfService": null,
        "support": null,
        "privacy": null,
        "marketing": null
    },
    "keyCredentials": [],
    "knownClientApplications": [],
    "logoUrl": null,
    "logoutUrl": null,
    "name": "xxxxx",
    "oauth2AllowIdTokenImplicitFlow": true,
    "oauth2AllowImplicitFlow": true,
    "oauth2Permissions": [],
    "oauth2RequirePostResponse": false,
    "optionalClaims": null,
    "orgRestrictions": [],
    "parentalControlSettings": {
        "countriesBlockedForMinors": [],
        "legalAgeGroupRule": "Allow"
    },
    "passwordCredentials": [
        {
            "customKeyIdentifier": null,
            "endDate": "2099-12-31T12:00:00Z",
            "keyId": "xxxxx",
            "startDate": "2018-06-07T07:58:18.4289954Z",
            "value": null,
            "createdOn": "2018-06-07T07:58:21.1632167Z",
            "hint": "gpi",
            "displayName": null
        }
    ],
    "preAuthorizedApplications": [],
    "publisherDomain": "xxxx.onmicrosoft.com",
    "replyUrlsWithType": [
        {
            "url": "http://localhost:8080/msgraph/callback",
            "type": "Web"
        }
    ],
    "requiredResourceAccess": [
        {
            "resourceAppId": "xxxxx",
            "resourceAccess": [
                {
                    "id": "64a6cdd6-aab1-4aaf-94b8-3cc8405e90d0",
                    "type": "Scope"
                },
                {
                    "id": "7427e0e9-2fba-42fe-b0c0-848c9e6a8182",
                    "type": "Scope"
                },
                {
                    "id": "37f7f235-527c-4136-accd-4a02d197296e",
                    "type": "Scope"
                },
                {
                    "id": "14dad69e-099b-42c9-810b-d002981feec1",
                    "type": "Scope"
                },
                {
                    "id": "465a38f9-76ea-45b9-9f34-9e8b0d4b0b42",
                    "type": "Scope"
                },
                {
                    "id": "2b9c4092-424d-4249-948d-b43879977640",
                    "type": "Scope"
                },
                {
                    "id": "570282fd-fa5c-430d-a7fd-fc8dc98a9dca",
                    "type": "Scope"
                },
                {
                    "id": "7b9103a5-4610-446b-9670-80643382c1fa",
                    "type": "Scope"
                },
                {
                    "id": "f45671fb-e0fe-4b4b-be20-3d3ce43f1bcb",
                    "type": "Scope"
                },
                {
                    "id": "88d21fd4-8e5a-4c32-b5e2-4a1c95f34f72",
                    "type": "Scope"
                },
                {
                    "id": "e1fe6dd8-ba31-4d61-89e7-88639da4683d",
                    "type": "Scope"
                },
                {
                    "id": "b340eb25-3456-403f-be2f-af7a0d370277",
                    "type": "Scope"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "samlMetadataUrl": null,
    "signInUrl": "http://localhost:8080/",
    "signInAudience": "AzureADandPersonalMicrosoftAccount",
    "tags": [
        "guidedSetupCreatedOrUpdated",
        "appModelVersion:2",
        "accessTokenVersion:1",
        "availableToOtherTenants:true",
        "supportsConvergence:true"
    ],
    "tokenEncryptionKeyId": null
}
```

Comment: Please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-permissions-and-consent#offline_access

Comment: Hi test123, I followed this manual exactly. Although I add the offline_access scope to the request for an access code and to the request of the bearer token, MSGraph refuses to return a refresh_token.

Comment: Is that you add the offline_access to you scope but you cannot get refresh_token?

Comment: Yes that is the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The request body you posted above isn't in `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. Since you're getting an `access_token`, I'm assuming this is just what you're providing to whichever library you're using to make the actual HTTP request. Just in case, the actual request body should look something like this (line breaks for readability):

```
grant_type=authorization_code&
code=[AUTHORIZATION CODE]&
client_id=[APPLICATION ID]&
client_secret=[PASSWORD]&
scope=[SCOPE]&
redirect_uri=[REDIRECT URI]
```

The values your sending looking correct to me with one exception, you shouldn't be passing `prompt=consent` at this stage.

The `prompt` parameter is used to force the user to consent during the interactive 1st phase of the flow, not when retrieving the token in the 2nd. It *shouldn't* result in the behavior you're experiencing but "shouldn't" and "doesn't" are often not the same thing.

If, however, you've added `offline_access` after the user has consented *and* you're *only* passing `prompt=consent` at this stage, it is possible your app has not received consent for `offline_access` yet. The token response will only provide scopes that have been consented.

If the user hasn't consented to one of the requested scopes, it will simply not provide that permission rather than returning an error. This allows your app to compare the scopes returned to the scopes requested and allow you to determine if you need to request a reconsent.

To understand why this is/how this works, imagine you request both `User.Read.All` and `User.ReadBasic.All`. Since `User.Read.All` requires Admin Consent, it is possible for a user to login to your app before administrative consent has been granted. In that case, your app may fall back to using `User.ReadBasic.All` as an alternative. The only difference to the user would be the data you show them would be limited (i.e. maybe your app wants to show `displayName` and `birthday` but can fall back to only `displayName`).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Actually we don't need the prompt=consent parameter, but I moved it to de authentication call. The user is then always prompted for the offline_access consent (and the other scope parameters). But unfortunately it still doesn't work. The response body contains other scope parameters than the request body. Also, when I remove some scope parameters from the request body, the response body returns more scope parameters than the request body!

Comment: Is this a traditional Azure AD instance or Azure AD B2C?

Comment: Did you include offline_access scope in the request for code?

Comment: I have included the offline_access in the request for code. It asks the user for consent on offline_access each time, now that I have added prompt=consent to the request for code.

Comment: I think it is a traditional Azure AD instance, but not sure. It is at an university and the instance is for  students and employees only.

Answer (score 0):

I have analyzed the response from Microsoft today and now it contains the refresh_token! It seems that the is some delay since it did'nt work thursday but works now on monday. 
The returned scope in the response still doesn't contain offline_access but the refresh_token parameter is now deliverd.

Thanks for your contributions!